# Why computer prints random characters if I print more than 5 pages?

Tags: windows, printing, printer, anti-virus

Why computer prints random characters if I print more than 5 pages?

Whenever I want to print a lot of pages, the printer prints the first 5 pages correctly, but them goes on a rampage an prints non stop random characters. This makes me waste so much paper. It never happened on my previous printer. Why is that?

Comment: What Windows version? What printer? Do you have latest drivers installed? What happens if you print more than 5 pages into XPS or PDF (instead of printing to paper)? And why you used anti-virus tag?

Comment: Sounds like the printer outputs a lot of 'post-script'. That is, the software driver Windows is using probably not the correct one for the printer. I would suggest looking up the make and model of the printer on the manufacturer's site and installing the recommended one. Excellent suggestions by miroxlav, print couple of pages of text file, then Word documents or such to PDF, then print the PDF files one page at the time and see what happens.

Comment: While it is probably drivers and/or software updates needed.  Depending if your printing images or not you could be running out of printer memory.

Comment: Tell Windows to just print pages 5-9 does that work?